# How to add GPS support in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to add gps location in my application.How can i do this?What kind of UI i need to to impliment?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want this:

[CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html) from apple shows how to get coordinates from GPS, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/06/04/how-to-add-gps-to-your-ios-app-part-1/) is a wonderful tutorial for implementing Location services in your iOS App.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)